# Blender: Water flow emitter parented to an animated armiture not working

Tags: blender

The scene is an animated fire hose that sees a house plant on fire and hops over to put it out. In the example I am showing here, the domain for the liquid does not intersect the domain for the fire+smoke just to simplify, but eventually, my plan is for the water to spray onto the burning plant.

The domain for the liquid does not disappear when baked, and no water emits from the cylinder. The water-emitting cylinder is parented to the armature with automatic weights. It is not actually inside the domain until it is time for it to emit water. Flow is key-framed to be off until the cylinder is inside the domain. The hose nozzle is set as a collision-type effector but for now, the water emitter is all the way at the tip of it. I cannot post images inline yet so here are some links.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ser0.png) full screen shot

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A48OD.png) flow physics

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOEYF.png) domain physics 1

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Lda.png) domain physics 2

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUnvJ.png) effector physics

Any ideas why I am not getting any water?